# Prove a 2-Variable Function is Nonnegative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

### Question

How to prove

$$f(x,y)=\frac{4xy}{(x+y)^2} - \frac{x}{y} e^{1-\frac{x}{y}}$$

is nonnegative for $x,y>0$?

---

### Some Attempts

\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \frac{(x-y) e^{1-\frac{x}{y}}}{y^2} - \frac{(x-y)4y}{(x+y)^3} \\
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= \frac{(y-x) x e^{1-\frac{x}{y}}}{y^3} + \frac{(y-x)4y}{(x+y)^3}
\end{align}
Setting both to 0 gives

\begin{align}
    (x-y) \bigl((x+y)^3 e^{1-\frac{x}{y}} - 4y^3\bigr) &= 0 \\
    (y-x) \bigl((x+y)^3 x e^{1-\frac{x}{y}} + 4y^4\bigr) &= 0
\end{align}

where I can only see $x=y$ is a critical line on which $f(x,y)=0$.

---

### Plot

I don't have enough reputation to embed a figure, but [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/z8rpvebr) is the GeoGebra link for a visual proof.

Thank you very much for your attention and help!

Comment: The inequality can be written completely in terms of the single variable $\frac x y$. That should make the solution easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really appreciate @geetha290krm for the nice hint!

Replacing $t={x}/{y}$, the function becomes

$$f(t) = \frac{4t}{(t+1)^2} - t e^{1-t}$$

whose 1st order derivative is

$$\frac{df}{dt} = (t-1) \Bigl(e^{1-t} - \frac{4}{(t+1)^3}\Bigr)$$

Now an obvious root is $t_1=1$. On the other hand, Wolfram gives the other two real-valued roots

\begin{align}
    t_2 &= -3 W_0\left(-\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^{2/3}\right)-1 && \approx 0.227 \\
    t_3 &= -3 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^{2/3}\right)-1 && \approx 4.978
\end{align}

Evaluating $f(t)$ at those critical points

$$f(t_1) = 0, \quad f(t_2) \approx 0.111, \quad f(t_3) \approx 0.464$$

Together with $\lim_{t \to 0} f(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = 0$, we can conclude $f(t)$ is nonnegative for $t>0$. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rnedb8bge5) is a plot of $f(t)$.

Equivalently, $f(x,y)$ is nonnegative for $x,y>0$. Q.E.D.